# Querying a Group in a Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Struggling with how to do this on Firebase.. Could use some guidance..

I have this json setup like this:

```
{

"members" : {
    "-KO0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM" : {
      "title" : "joe"
    },
    "-KO0FPUtK6cS0ZtIOTz0" : {
      "title" : "jack"
    },
    "-KO0j-cLmxA-LxxFYUki" : {
      "title" : "john"
    }
  }

}
```

It is pretty simple. I am using Firebase's Javascript API. I am trying to figure out how to que ry specifically for a object that is equal to "joe". Or title:"jack". Any Ideas? I have only been able to pull everything under "members", and then parse through

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple enough:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild('title').equalTo('joe');
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Alternatively you can read the same query with:

```
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```